# Combining server and client side event handlers for xPage Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have been reviewing the postings online, as well as the postings by IBM and I'm still confused about how to get my form to submit.

I am using formvalidation.io validation and from CSJS, I get whether the validation is correct or not.  Then, I want to submit if it is correct, and not submit if it isn't.

I've tried different variations but get the same result.  If the validation is NOT correct, the form correctly continues to display and doesn't submit.  However, if the validation IS correct, the form does not submit.  I receive the error message XSP.executeOnServer is not a function and have tried various ways to resolve this without success. Here's my code:

```
<xp:button value="Join Our Team" id="button1">
   <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
      <xp:this.script><![CDATA[$(document).ready(function() {
         $(this).click(function(){
         $("form").data('formValidation').validate();
         var isValidForm = $("form").data('formValidation').isValid();
         if (isValidForm){
            XSP.executeOnServer('#{id:eventhandler1a}', '#{id:panel1}');
         }
         else {
            $("form").data('formValidation').validate();
            return false;
         }
     });
});]]></xp:this.script>

<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:XSP.executeOnServer = function () {
// the event handler id to be executed is the first argument, and is required
    if (!arguments[0])
        return false;
    var functionName = arguments[0];

// OPTIONAL - The Client Side ID that is partially refreshed after executing the event handler
    var refreshId = (arguments[1]) ? arguments[1] : "@none";
    var form = (arguments[1]) ? XSP.findForm(arguments[1]) : dojo.query('form')[0];

// catch all in case dojo element has moved object outside of form...
    if (!form)
        form = dojo.query('form')[0];

// OPTIONAL - Options object containing onStart, onComplete and onError functions for the call to the
    // handler and subsequent partial refresh
    var options = (arguments[2]) ? arguments[2] : {};

// OPTIONAL - Value to submit in $$xspsubmitvalue. can be retrieved using context.getSubmittedValue()
    var submitValue = (arguments[3]) ? arguments[3] : '';

// Set the ID in $$xspsubmitid of the event handler to execute
    dojo.query('[name="$$xspsubmitid"]')[0].value = functionName;
    dojo.query('[name="$$xspsubmitvalue"]')[0].value = submitValue;
    this._partialRefresh("post", form, refreshId, options);
}   }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xp:panel id="panel1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onClick" submit="true" id="eventhandler1a" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
    </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the spooky things that happens from time to time with Domino.  Now my code works with a simple return true or return false.  I had done this in the beginning and it was a real head scratcher why it wouldn't work.  I've had these type of things happen from time to time with Domino and it's always scary when you don't know why they occur.  But I'm happy that my clean, simple code works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use RPC, which will process the CS and return a go/no-go value to your SSJS to submit or not. Below is a full XPage you can use to see how it works. This just populates a viewScope, but I think it will give you how it works in a very simple way.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br>
 <xp:button value="CSJS"  id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[myRPC.myMethod("somevalue").addCallback(function(response) {
    alert("the response is " + response);
});]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

  <xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:jsonRpcService id="jsonRpcService1" serviceName="myRPC"
    state="true">
    <xe:this.methods>
      <xe:remoteMethod name="myMethod">
        <xe:this.arguments>
            <xe:remoteMethodArg name="myArg" type="string"></xe:remoteMethodArg>
        </xe:this.arguments>
        <xe:this.script>
            <![CDATA[
            print("invocation: " + myArg);
            viewScope.invokedBy = myArg;
            print("viewScope:" + viewScope.invokedBy);
            return viewScope.invokedBy;

          ]]>
        </xe:this.script>
      </xe:remoteMethod>
    </xe:this.methods>
  </xe:jsonRpcService>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{viewScope.invokedBy}"></xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Refresh" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:confirm>
                    <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "is: " + viewScope.invokedBy;}]]></xp:this.message>
                </xp:confirm>
            </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br></xp:view>
```

Comment: I've never used RPC before, but I think I see what you mean.  I'm going to read up on it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Brian, I don't think that will work from what I'm understanding, because the validation code is all csjs.  So I need to say on the client side whether or not the validation has passed.  And I can't pass the results of that to a scoped value, because from what I understand you can't set a scoped value using csjs.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think you can put your validation code into the RPC since that will execute CSJS, and you can pass the true/false of your validation to SSJS to do what you need. I posted a complete XPage, try putting it in a database as see it.

Comment: I got it working.  For some reason the code to save or not save with return true or return false wasn't working, but later when I tried it - it worked.  I've had this happen before with Domino.

Comment: I have too, I suspect it's cacheing, but I don't know for sure. I have a tendency to put a text "version" number on and increment it up on each change to confirm that the whole page is up.

Answer (score 0):

If CSJS in an eventHandler returns true, SSJS will fire. If it returns false, it won't. So `this.script` just needs to return true.

However, you're then posting CSJS in `this.action`. That property of the eventHandler takes SSJS, so `dojo.query` and `XSP.findForm` won't work. You need to put SSJS in there to save your document or whatever else you need to do.

Comment: I agree that if I have CSJS in an eventHandler and if it returns false it shouldn't continue to fire the SSJS.  But it does and that is what is confusing to me and why I started down this long convoluted path.  Have you any idea why the SSJS would continue even with a false return?

Comment: Sorry, I was replying to the part "However, if the validation IS correct, the form does not submit. I receive the error message XSP.executeOnServer is not a function...." As I say, your code in the `this.action` is CSJS where SSJS is required, so there are fundamental issues there, the code needs moving to somewhere that accepts CSJS. The onclick event on the Panel may be being triggered by something other than the success / failure of the button, I'd recommend changing it to "onBlah" since you don't seem to trigger a click. I think significant browser debugging is needed to resolve it.